# AWS Aurora MySQL Serverless CPU utilization is growing for unknown reason

Tags: mysql, aws, aurora, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

We have been using Aurora serverless databases in staging and production environments for a few months now, and find the CPU remains in the range 15-20% almost all the time. However in the past week the CPU utilisation has been growing, even during periods of zero load and is now at 38%. I'm worried this trend will continue further and begin to become an issue.

I saw the same trend in our Staging environment, but it only lasted 3 days and then returned to the usual level.

What could be driving this and how should I be debugging and resolving the root cause(s)?

[image: Chart from AWS database monitoring]

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

Returns only 6 rows.

[image: Results from SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST]

----- Update 4th Sept 2019 -----

In the end, I just continued to monitor it, and once it reached 50% it dropped back down. I guess it is a quirk of Aurora serverless? Would be great to hear from anyone else facing this issue as I hate not understanding things.

[image]

Comment: Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see what is running.  Use the "slowlog" to see what queries are taking a lot of time.  Meanwhile, I see that the "drop" occurs about midnight every night -- when Amazon do backups (or whatever)?

Comment: @RickJames I added the results of `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to the question.

Comment: Try again, or use the slowlog.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was setting the min and max instance count higher than before (forcing aurora to scale up, for example from min 2 ACU to min 4 ACU), and after scaling restoring the scaling settings.

I used 'Force scaling the capacity to the specified values when the timeout is reached' and 'Apply immediately'.

It also solved another issue we had, the 'Serverless database capacity' indicated 4 ACU while it was actually 2 ACU (as seen in the picture)

[image: we expect 45% cpu with 2 instances, not 80%]